# How to symlink a device throught udev and always point to the same device?

Tags: udev

I have the following udev rule for a USB thermal printer that works with serial through usb:

`SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c8a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3001", SYMLINK+="ttyS99", MODE="0660", GROUP="lp"`

output of `ls -la`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 ago 21 10:50 /dev/ttyS99 -> ttyACM1
```

but if I power it off and on again, it symlinks to the wrong device:

output of `ls -la` after powering off and on again:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 ago 22 13:28 /dev/ttyS99 -> bus/usb/001/008
```

How can I make it always point to ttyACM1 ?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer: I added `SUBSYSTEM=="tty"` at the start:

`SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c8a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3001", SYMLINK+="ttyS99", MODE="0660", GROUP="lp"`

Answer (score -1):

Change `SUBSYSTEMS` to `SUBSYSTEM` in the usb rule in your initial ruleset and then it will work.

Comment: This does answer the question. I have now reformulated.

Comment: the case is that the SUBSYSTEM="tty" part is not needed. Problem is that OP had the spelling error in the first place

Comment: The tty is needed since he communicates to usb via serial.

Comment: that wont be needed until the bind event - the SUBSYSTEM=usb will catch it at the add event.